# Can the third sex be categorized as Male or Female?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, terminology

[Hijra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijra_%28South_Asia%29) are people who have a penis (not sure if sexually active) but look much like a female (perhaps for some feminine biological property). Wikipedia says they are *"physiological males who have feminine gender identity"*

Also, I just came to know there are some more types of [third gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender) people.

Now, **is there really any *BIOLOGICAL* third gender** which cannot be categorized as male or female? Or its always possible to categorize them to male or female?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When dealing with *humans*, there are only two **Biological** genders as defined by the presence or absence of the Y-Chromosome. If the Y-Chromosome is not present, or through some process gets totally deactivated, the human will appear and function as a Female.

XX = Female

XY = Male

XXY = Male (Klinefelter's Syndrome)

XYY = Male (Aneuploidy - Normal Functioning Males)

XXX = Female (Aneuploidy - Normal Functioning Females)

X = Female (Turner's Syndrome - Generally infertile, other issues)

Y = Fatal (The Y-Chromosome is drastically smaller than the X-Chromosome, which contains many *necessary* genes)

XXYY = Male

...

The list goes on, since there have been records of up to XXXXX.

If there is a Y-Chromosome present, the human born will be male.

However, that is not to say that a person cannot **psychologically** identify as something else. It's also worth noting that the majority of known species are asexual and do not have genders, and that those which do have genders do not always follow the same rules (Fruit Flies, for instance, use the *ratio* of genes to determine sex).

Comment: That one is really a nice answer. I did not take biology in school (planned to be engineer) but I did know about X-Y chromosomes. However, I always thought its only XX and XY!

Comment: There is also the [barr body test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barr_body) to determine sex. When present, the organism is said to be female. Using the barr body test XXY is female and X is male. There is a certain lack of consensus on what makes a sex male or female and we normally revert to how the individual identifies, which is not particularly scientific.

Comment: How do you deal with [XX males without SRY gene and with infertility](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11278224)?

Comment: @Remi.b -- The missing SRY gene in a phenotypical male with XX chromosomes is a really interesting exception to the general rule I described above. Thanks for bringing it up in the comments! I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 18):

I think you might be confusing *sex* and *gender*. The terms are often used interchangeably, but strictly speaking, they have different biological meanings. [Sex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex) refers to the biological categorization based on genetics, reproductive organs, or similar things, whereas [gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender) is based on social identity.

For humans, there are only two sex chromosomes, X and Y, and they determine the male and female sexes. But there are many situations that don't fall under the XX/XY categorization, and people with these conditions are usually referred to as [intersex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex). These can include conditions such as congenital adrenal hyperplasia, androgen insensitivity syndrome, and 5-alpha-reductase deficiency. So in short, there is no biological third *sex*, but that doesn't mean you can always categorize a person as biologically male or female.

As you quoted, the hijira are usually physiologically male but have a different *gender* identity.

Comment: Yeah, I was not aware of the difference between gender and sex. But I mentioned *Biological Gender* which IMO implies the technical term `sex` as you explained. Thanks for explaining the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the Wikipedia article you reference, its useful to remember that conventional chromosomal definitions of gender, the genitals are soft tissue which has many recorded morphological abnormalities.  [hermaphrodites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermaphrodite#Humans) and a [spectrum of tissue shapes do occur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex) to the extent that the conventional gender identity is not acceptable.

Physiological definition of gender, despite the chromosomes do need to be medically and socially addressed.  I am not sure that all these 'intersex' people really should be grouped into a single 'third sex', but some way of recognizing their essential human rights should be out there in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @MCM answer, there are also chromosomal crossover that might happen between non homologous. You can have some of the genes of Y chromosome going to X chromosome or elsewhere, for instance, further expanding the possibilities for different sexualities...

Answer (score -2):

There is an actual third gender. That is true hermaphroditism. Some humans are true hermaphrodites. The most common cause of this? 2 eggs fusing, 1 male and 1 female before they start differentiation.

These have both male and female characteristics and so they can't be classified as either male or female.

Here is my source:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_hermaphroditism

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Yeah I just now added it

Comment: From your source: "There are no documented cases in which both types of gonadal tissue function."  Based on this, human "true hermaphrodites" can always be classified as either "reproductively male" or "reproductively female", never a mix.

Comment: 1) Hermaphrodites don't occur in humans — you may be confusing this with intersexuality. 2) Eggs don't have a sex and I don't think there's ever been a record of an egg containing an Y-chromosome so this doesn't seem to make any sense. 3) if you have evidence that two egg cells have ever been observed to fuse and lead to a viable child please post it here – since even small trisomies are typically fatal or in rare cases *only* have severe developmental problems (e.g. Down's syndrome) the current understanding is that a triploid human is not possible.