# Is it possible to correctly identify presence of Y chromosome with external physical test only?

Tags: human-biology, chromosome

I asked a [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/3315/1308) related to the third sex, and I came to know that its always possible to categorize a human to male or female with presence of Y chromosome.

Now, I have another question. Is there a way to say if someone has Y chromosome **only with external physical test**? More specifically:

- Someone has a penis, can we say that s/he will have Y chromosome?
- Some one has Y chromosome, can we say that he will have a penis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, an external physical examination would be inconclusive. The reason is the TDF
gene. To be more specific, if a person has XY and the gene is not active then the subject
would have a female appearance. Also we cannot conclude that a person has a Y
chromosome even if it has penis because that gene could be transferred on the X chromosome.

Here is a reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testis_determining_factor.

Comment: Isn't it the SRY gene which expresses the TDF transcription factor?

Comment: Sometimes, the area which encodes this protein is referred as TDF gene, although I am not sure if this terminology is abusive. http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/TDF_gene . Also see here http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene?term=testis%20determinding%20factor  a alias for the SRY gene is TDF.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting condition is [androgen insentivity syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgen_insensitivity_syndrome). In AIS, the body is unable to respond to androgens, the male sex hormone, of which testosterone is the best known. The most common cause is a defective androgen receptor, and most of these diseases are X-linked. In extreme cases, [complete androgen insensitivy syndrome (CAIS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_androgen_insensitivity_syndrome) can occur. Genetic males (XY) with CAIS appear outwardly as females due to the lack of androgens that would normally lead to masculinzation. However, the SRY gene (sex-determining region Y) that encodes TDF still causes testes to develop, although they are usually internal. Individuals with CAIS generally identify as females.